# SQL query to exclude original rows which there is a copy of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In MyTable I have a column named CopyOf which holds the ID of other original row from the same table (MyTable). I want to select all rows except the original rows which there is a Copy of them. But I don't know how to manage conditions both in "ON" and "WHERE"

```
Select * from MyTable a left join  MyTable b on ?????? where ???????
```

Sample data:

ID    |   CopyOf

1      |

2      |

3      |      1

I want just to select rows 2 and 3 because there is a copy of 1.

Comment: Sample data and expected Result will help us to understand better

Comment: Help us help you - please share the some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: Put JOIN conditions in the ON clause. Put a conditions in WHERE. Put b conditions in ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in a join and where then use a query like the one below;

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM MyTable a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
    ON a.ID = b.CopyOf
WHERE b.CopyOf IS NULL
```

This will join the table back to itself and then ignore any that are a copy of something in the same table.

Another option you appear to have is that you can just look for everything that isn't a copy of something else, like this;

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.CopyOf IS NULL
```

Another option is this;

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT CopyOf FROM MyTable)
```

Which will exclude any ID's completely that have a record in the CopyOf field. This final one will return only ID's that don't have any copies at all. Re-reading your question, I think this final query is the one you're after.

Comment: The First and third solutions are fine. But the second solution is removing the rows which are copy not the original rows.

Comment: Sure, it's difficult to work out the question without sample data and the expected output. Glad one of these has fixed it for you. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Sorry. I have added sample data and the result I am looking for. I think there is a "JOIN" needed because I want to exclude original rows but keep the copies.

Comment: Sure, that final query should do what you're after. It will only return rows with an ID that isn't in the CopyOf Field

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to show all data that is not available from table2. Here's my solution

Use `NOT IN` in your `WHERE` Clause.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM MyTable2)
```

Comment: Sorry My question is about a single table. So I think a "JOIN" or perhaps "ALIAS" names are needed.